# compare an integer number without using calculator

Tags: arithmetic

we have $\displaystyle a=2^{12}$ and $\displaystyle b=3^8$ and I wonder if exist method to compare them without using calculator.

Comment: Really you need to show more effort than this and explain what you have tried. You will learn very little if you didn't spend some time puzzling it out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the fourth root of both, they are $2^3=8$ and $3^2=9$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^8 = \left(\dfrac{9}{4}\right)^4 > 2^4 = 16 \Longrightarrow 3^8 > 16*2^8 = 2^4*2^8 = 2^{12}$. So $2^{12} < 3^8$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $p, q$ are positive integers with $p\lt q$ then $p^2\lt q^2$

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, do the calculations *by hand*, especially if you remember that $2^{10}=1024$, so that $2^{12}=1024\times4=4096$, in which case it suffices to make some crude estimates on $3^8$:

$$3^4=81\Longrightarrow3^6=81\times9\gt700\Longrightarrow3^8\gt700\times9=6300$$

or

$$3^4\gt80\Longrightarrow3^8\gt80^2=6400$$